# SKI combinator calculus or starship operator in F#

Tags: f#, functional-programming, ml, calculus

Assuming we have two functions:

one that has a single parameter, like a partially applied addition:

```
let plus1 = (+) 1 
// the same as let plus1 x = 1 + x
```

another that expects two parameters, like a multiplication:

```
let mult = (*)
```

we can now create a

```
let addOneAndMultiply x = mult x (plus1 x)
```

f x (g x) is usually called a SKI combinator calculus

in haskell, functions like that can be shortened with a starship <*> operator:

```
//haskell
mult <*> plus1
```

Is there any way to do the same SKI trick in F# ?

Comment: Genuine question: Do you feel this keeps the code clearer and/or more likely to be correct? Because to me it's confusing and I would likely misuse it. I enjoy the fact that idiomatic F# is free of combinators like this.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox Personally, I like combinators and use them in F#, but only in certain circumstances.  I probably wouldn't use one for something with a trivial expanded form, but for something like error-handling, where you want to apply `f` if everything is `Ok` but return the appropriate `Error` if something has gone wrong, I think combinators make it easier to read and understand than something like nested pattern-matches.

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach Ah, I can see the usefulness for a common pattern like that, where the type differences help ensure correct use as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple to do this in F#:

```
let (<*>) f g x = f x (g x)
```

To demonstrate that this works:

```
let plus1 = (+) 1
let mult = (*)
let addOneAndMultiply = mult <*> plus1

addOneAndMultiply 2 // Result: 6
addOneAndMultiply 3 // Result: 12
addOneAndMultiply 4 // Result: 20
```

P.S. If you want to make it a function instead of an operator, you just have to replace the `(<*>)` with the name of the function you want to define:

```
let starling f g x = f x (g x)
```

Comment: As a side note, some F# frameworks have a function called `apply` that does this, and may or may not also define the `<*>` operator.  Unlike Haskell, in F# you have to define a different function/operator for each type of Applicative.

Comment: Unless the library is [FSharpPlus](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpPlus) which provides a generic `<*>` operator and you don't need to be switching definitions for different types.